# BadPaddingException: Decryption error while encrypting and decrypting a file using RSA with symmetrics Key in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, rsa

I am doing a project to learn about encryption and decryption. I encrypt a file (input file) and encrypt the symmetric key using RSA public. Then I decrypt the symmetric key using RSA private key and then decrypt the file(output file).

here below is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class Main {
    public static SecretKey generateKey(int n) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(n);
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        return key;
    }
    public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }

    public static void encryptFile(String algorithm, SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv,
                                   File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            if (output != null) {
                outputStream.write(output);
            }
        }
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        if (outputBytes != null) {
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static void decryptFile(String algorithm, SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv,
                                   File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            if (output != null) {
                outputStream.write(output);
            }
        }
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        if (outputBytes != null) {
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        return pair;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, RuntimeException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        //generating a symmetric key
        SecretKey secKey = generateKey(128);
        //generating an IV
        IvParameterSpec iv=generateIv();

        //encrypt the data with AES
        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/nm-ca/IdeaProjects/RSA/src/inputFile.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("C:/Users/nm-ca/IdeaProjects/RSA/src/outputFile.txt");
        encryptFile("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding",secKey,iv,inputFile,outputFile);

        //RSA pair of keys generation
        PrivateKey privateKey = generateKeyPair().getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = generateKeyPair().getPublic();

        //encrypt the symmetric key with RSA public key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());

        //decrypt the symmentric key with RSA private Key
        cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey , 0, decryptedKey .length, "AES");

        //Decrypt the cipher text using decrypted symmetric key
        decryptFile("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", originalKey,iv,outputFile,inputFile);
    }
}
```

When I execute this, I get an BadPaddingException: Decryption error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLQdb.png)

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: `generateKeyPair()` generates a *different* key pair every time you call it. You must use the public and private keys from a single pair to accomplish your task.